# How to create sequence with thread.sleep in Java

Tags: java, arrays, image, swing, jlabel

I'm trying to create a simple sequence that basically consists on a JLabel's text being set to a value using an array and a for cycle. However it waits a certain time, before it changes.

My code looks something like this:

```java
private String[] images = {"ball_00.bmp",
            "ball_01.bmp",
            "ball_02.bmp",
            "ball_03.bmp",
            "ball_04.bmp",
            "ball_05.bmp",
            "ball_06.bmp",
            "ball_07.bmp",
            "ball_08.bmp",
            "ball_09.bmp",
            "ball_10.bmp"};

    public void runGif(){
        for(int x = 0; x < this.images.length; x++) {
            try {
                System.out.println(images[x]);
                this.lbl_image.setText(images[x]);
                this.panel_CENTER.add(lbl_image);
                this.lbl_image.setVisible(false);
                this.lbl_image.setVisible(true);
                
                System.out.println("I'm waiting");
                Thread.sleep(CurrentSpeed);
                System.out.println("I'm back");
                }
            catch(Exception e) {e.getStackTrace();}
            System.out.println(x);
        }
    }
```

However I'm getting no output and the only thing I see on my JFrame is the label displaying "GIF", which is the default text that I set it to.

I don't know what migth be causing this issue, and would be very grateful if someone could help me.

Thank you for your attention in advance!

Comment: Ah, the wonderful world of concurrency.  You're going to want to start by having a look at [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) to better understand the problem you're trying to solve and [How to Use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for what the solution will need to be based on

Comment: Remember, Swing is NOT thread safe and is single threaded.  This means, you should not update the UI (or any state that the UI relies on) from outside of the context of the Event Dispatching Thread, and, you should not execute any long running or blocking within context of the EDT